# What does this if-statement from a bash script do?

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to bash scripting and learning through some examples. One of the examples that I saw is using an if-statement to test if a previously assigned output file is valid, like this:

```
if [ -n "$outputFile" ] && ! 2>/dev/null : >> $outputFile ; then
    exit 1
fi
```

I understand what `[ -n "$outputFile" ]` does but not the rest of the conditional. Can someone explain what `! 2>/dev/null : >> $outputFile` mean/does?

I have googled for answers but most links found were explanations on I/O redirection, which are definitely relevant but still unclear about the `! : >>` structure.

Comment: Where did you see it? And what did it say it does?

Comment: Could be rewritten as `if [[ $outputFile ]] && [[ ! -w $outputFile ]]; then exit; fi`

Comment: @glennjackman: `-w` assumes the file already exists, so it's not exactly the same.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I found the if-statement in this script: [link](http://www.isi.edu/~yuri/dupx/). The basic idea of this script is to redirect running process's I/O to specified files. The if-statement is used in dupx to test whether a file is write-able.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's some oddly written code!

The `:` command is built into bash. It's equivalent to `true`; it does nothing, successfully.

```
: >> $outputFile
```

attempts to do nothing, and appends the (empty) output to `$outputFile` -- which has already been confirmed to be a non-empty string. The `>>` redirection operator will create the file if it doesn't already exist.

I/O redirections such as `2>/dev/null` can appear anywhere in a simple command; they don't have to be at the end. So the stdout of the `:` command (which is empty) is appended to `$outputFile`, and any stderr output is redirected to /dev/null. Any such stderr output would be the result of a failure in the redirection, since the `:` command itself does nothing and won't fail to do so. I don't know why the redirection of stdout (onto the end of `$outputFile` and the redirection of stderr (to `/dev/null`) are on opposite sides of the `:` command.

The `!` operator is a logical "not"; it checks whether the following command succeeded, and inverts the result.

The net result, written in English-ish text is:

if "$outputFile" is set and is not an empty string, **and** if we don't have permission to write to it, then terminate the script with a status of 1.

In short, it tests whether we're able to write to `$outputFile`, and bails out if we don't.

Comment: One up for the thorough explanation! About why "the redirection of stderr (to /dev/null) are on opposite sides of the : command", I did some testing. A read-only file /tmp/bob is created and I ran both `2>/dev/null : >> /tmp/bob` and `: >> /tmp/bob 2>/dev/null`. The former prints nothing and the latter prints `bash: /tmp/bob: Permission denied`.

Comment: @GongyuWang: That's odd; after `2>/dev/null : >> /tmp/bob` I get `$?` = 0 (and an empty `/tmp/bob` file). I get `$?` = 1 if I first create `/tmp/bob` as a directory or as a file I can't write (which, now that I actually read your entire comment, I realize is what you did).

Comment: @GongyuWang: I can avoid the error message by using `: 2>/dev/null >> /tmp/bob`. The `2>/dev/null` has to precede the `>> /tmp/bob`; it doesn't have to precede the `:` command.

Comment: I had confusions with how if-statements work in bash. I thought it was like C but it isn't in that "if its return status (of the conditional-part) is zero, the then-part is executed".

Comment: @GongyuWang: Right. A return status of 0 denotes success; anything else denotes failure. Shell conditions are success vs. failure, not true vs. false. (`/bin/true` sets the exit status to 0; `/bin/false` sets it to 1.)

Comment: I find it extremely curious that the stderr redirection (`2>/dev/null`) can actually shove the error message from the _command line_ into a file at all.  I consider the `>> /tmp/bob` redirection to be a part of the command line, not a part of the command (`:`).  The thing giving you the error is not the `:` command, but the whole line.  In contrast, Zsh will tell you that the redirection to /tmp/bob failed regardless of where you put the `2>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 4):

The script is attempting to make sure `$outputFile` is writable in a not-so-obvious way.

`:` is the null command in `bash`, it does nothing. The fact that `stderr` is redirected to `/dev/null` is simply to suppress the permission denied error, should one occur.

If the file is not writable, then the command fails, which makes the condition true since it's negated with `!` and the script exits.

Comment: Good and concise answer! Thanks.